# Downloading a bytearray with Flex 3/Flash 9

Tags: flash, apache-flex, save

I am trying to save a file to a user specified location, but am running into problems with Flex 3/Flash Player 9.

I originally made this work using Flash 4.6 with the following code:

```
protected function pdfBth_printPDF(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var createPDF:PDF = new PDF(Orientation.PORTRAIT, Unit.MM, Size.A4)
    var image:ImageSnapshot = ImageSnapshot.captureImage(albumListGrid, 500, new JPEGEncoder());
    var resize:Resize = new Resize (Mode.RESIZE_PAGE, Position.CENTERED);
    createPDF.addPage();
    createPDF.addImageStream(image.data, ColorSpace.DEVICE_RGB, resize);

    var ba:ByteArray = createPDF.save(Method.LOCAL);
    new FileReference().save(ba,"AlbumList.pdf");       
}
```

This worked perfectly, taking a snapshot of a list grid, turning it into a PDF, and saving in a chosen location.

The problem is `FileReference.save` does not exist in Flex 3 with Flash Player 9 (From what I can tell). How do I do the same functionality using Flex 3/FP9?  I want all work to be done on the client's side, and upgrading Flex or FP is not an option currently. Any help is appreciated!!!

Comment: Are you using ActionScript 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex 3 or Flash player 9 do not support saving files locally. The only workaround for this is to upload the file to a server and then download it from there.

Take a look at [this example](http://designreviver.com/tutorials/actionscript-3-jpeg-encoder-revealed-saving-images-from-flash/) which explains how to do it.

Comment: Ok. That is kind of what I saw when I was researching, just hoping for a work-around. Thanks!

Comment: @user2921015 for a possible workaround... If your app (SWF) runs in a browser, you could try using `externalInterface` to pass the `ba` byte values to some Javascript array then maybe use html code (or trigger some JS function) to bring up a save dialog... Investigate that option.